# traversing directories with php?

Tags: php, relative-path, realpath, directory-traversal

I have a path to a folder (e.g. `/var/www/tester/assets/themes/default/css/`).

a user can provide a relative path to the folder, so for example. `layout/ie7.css` would give the path of `/var/www/tester/assets/themes/default/css/layout/ie7.css`.

This works fine, however I want the users to be able to navigate up the directory tree as well.

so with the path to the css folder again if a user provides `../../cache/css/ie7.css` I want the path to end up as `/var/www/tester/assets/themes/default/cache/css/ie7.css`.

I thought I could just pass them together to [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) e.g:

```
$base = '/var/www/tester/assets/themes/default/css/';
$user_path = '../../cache/css/ie7.css';
$final_path = realpath($base.$user_path);
```

But that just returns false. How can I do this?

Comment: Does php has the right to open shis folder? Try it with clean path '/var/www/tester/assets/themes/cache/css/ie7.css', and see what you get

Comment: "The running script must have executable permissions on all directories in the hierarchy, otherwise realpath() will return FALSE." - from the docs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all the real path function also checks whether the given path exists... Are you sure your path exists???

```
/var/www/tester/assets/themes/default/css/../../cache/css/ie7.css
```

would not end up in

```
/var/www/tester/assets/themes/default/cache/css/ie7.css
```

as you suggest but it ends up in

```
/var/www/tester/assets/themes/cache/css/ie7.css
```

Does this folder with the given file exist?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't. There is nothing wrong with a path like `/var/www/tester/assets/themes/default/css/../../cache/css/ie7.css`. It works on all OSes and browsers.

Note: are you aware that you might be creating a security risk here? What if users provide `../../../../../../../etc/passwd` ?

Comment: I use "users" in the wrong context. They are users of of a php library I am creating. The path of provided by a config file. No security risk. The "user" could write his own script to do that. Good tip though.

Comment: Also, wouldn't there be some (probably negligible, but still some) overhead from having to translate that path if it is used multiple times?